# Getting value from Javascript to url to Iframe

Tags: javascript, html

I want to return `value` to the URL so that I can play the video in iframe

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>JavaScript - read JSON from URL</title>
    <script>
        var getJSON = function(url, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', url, true);
  xhr.responseType = 'json';
  xhr.onload = function() {
    var status = xhr.status;
    if (status === 200) {
      callback(null, xhr.response);
    } else {
      callback(status, xhr.response);
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
};

getJSON('http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/19995/videos?api_key=06412c2ac60d3b3a66c7fb129dcaca28&append_to_response=videos',
function(err, data) {
if (err !== null) {
  alert('Something went wrong: ' + err);
} else {
  const value=data.results[0].key;
  document.getElementById("y").innerHTML =
  value;

}

});</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="mypanel"></div>
 <p id="y"></p>
 <iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" data-video="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+value+
 src="" frameborder="0" autoplay allowfullscreen></iframe>
 </body>
</html>
```

I can get value by Id but how can I append it in the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use native `JS fetch API` to get the results from your url. You do not need to use `xhr` or extra lines of `code`.

You need to set `src` of your iframe dynamically via `getJSON` results. At current you are only setting the `data-attribute` which you can use later for something else. A data attribute will **not** embed the video in your iframe.

Also, to play the YT `video` in the `iframe` you need to `embed` the `src` in your `iframe` like this:

```
'https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+value
```

Final Code should be this to use:

```
//Call API
fetch("http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/19995/videos?api_key=06412c2ac60d3b3a66c7fb129dcaca28&append_to_response=videost")
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    const value = data.results[0].key
    //Apply HTML src
    document.getElementById("ytplayer").src = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+value
    //Set Data-Attribute
    document.getElementById("ytplayer").setAttribute('data-video', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+value)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the `<iframe>` element, not the `<p>` above it. You also need to use `setAttribute()` to set the `data-video` attribute.

```
getJSON('http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/19995/videos?api_key=06412c2ac60d3b3a66c7fb129dcaca28&append_to_response=videos',
  function(err, data) {
  if (err !== null) {
    alert('Something went wrong: ' + err);
  } else {
    const value=data.results[0].key;
    document.getElementById('ytplayer').setAttribute('data-video', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + value)
  }
});
```

Comment: `<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" data-video="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+value src="" frameborder="0" autoplay allowfullscreen></iframe>` How should I make change in HTML?